# Recursion Error in Array Sum

Tags: java

I am trying to sum up the elements of an array. When I test my code the sum is always off by one. For example if I input: 20, 40,30 it gives me 89 instead of 90. I'm not exactly sure what I am doing wrong. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great! Thanks

This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int size = kbd.nextInt();
    int [] myArray = new int [size]
    //user inputs the elements of array
    for(int i =0; i<myArray.length; i++){
        myArray[i]= kbd.nextInt();
    }
    int total = sumNum(myArray,0, myArray.length-1)
    System.out.println("The sum is"+ total);
}

public static int sumNum(int [] array, int begin, int end){
    if(begin > last) {
        return -1; 
    }
    else {
        int total = sumNum(array, begin +1, end)+ array[first]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `return -1` doing?  Running out of array elements doesn't actually affect your sum so you should return 0.

Comment: Your code contains a lot of syntax errors - make it compilable and probably it will solve your problems. Use debugger and a small size of array to find the root cause

Comment: I just generally wrote the code on here not necessarily with all the syntax. I have this code running and compiling. i just need some help with figuring out the logic error

Comment: So where's your return statement in sumNum for the `else`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base case is wrong:
Let's say you are summing up `int[] A = {1}`, and expand your recursion function call as follow:

```
sumNum(A, 0, 0) = sumNum(A, 1, 0) + A[0] = -1 + A[0]
```

You see, finally `sumNum(A, 1, 0)` returns `-1` and we get `A[0] - 1` as result.

So the correct solutions is `sumNum(A, 1, 0)` returning `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this can be improved upon and its not tail recursive but how about :

```
   public class Recurs {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int [] myArray = new int[]{20,40,30} ;

        int total = sumNum(myArray,0);

        System.out.println("The sum is "+ total);
    }

    public static int sumNum(int [] array, int begin){
        if(begin == array.length) {
            return 0; 
        }
        else {
            return sumNum(array, begin + 1) + array[begin];
        }
    }

}
```